# Monitor Popen process in python

Tags: python, multithreading, macos, subprocess, popen

I have a function that launches a command that is running in background as seen below:

```
import subprocess
import threading
import time
import sys



def server():
    def launch_server():
        init = ['something']
        p = subprocess.Popen(init)
        while p.poll() is None:
            try:
                time.sleep(0.5)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print ("Ctrl-c was requested")
                sys.exit(0)

            else:
            launch_server()
thread = threading.Thread(target=launch_server)
thread.start()
return
```

I use poll() to know if it is running, and I use threading so that this function does not block my code. Now, If I kill `init` with `killall init` the `while` loop is able to relaunch `init`. However, If I press `Ctrl-c` the application does not die. Indeed, it is relaunched and the only way to stop this is to kill using the *Activity monitor* (I am on Mac OSX). I am failing to see what the problem is with the `try` section of my code. I should add that it is the first time I am faced to the use of threading (maybe that's the problem?). I would be glad if someone could tell me what the error is. Thanks in advance.

**Update**

After @zondo comment, I found that it was quite easy to solve the problem for this case. I had to add:

```
thread.daemon = True
```

Just before `thread.start()` see [the documentation here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon).

Comment: Why do you create a separate thread in the first place?  Why not just say `lunch_server()`?  Anyway, `return` is invalid syntax outside of a function.

Comment: @zondo Because I am calling other functions after this one in my main program. The time.sleep() part blocks the subsequent functions.

Comment: The problem is that only the main thread can catch `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Comment: @zondo thanks, you were right. I fixed it.